# Wordpress not applying template to blog page

Tags: html, wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong... I have built a theme for my blog that worked on my local server(using mamp) when I was building on that. Since then I've moved my site online but now the template for the blog doesn't get applied to the blog page. [Here is the blog](http://digitalbrent.com/blog). I have checked in the admin where it points to that template file. It is indeed pointing to the correct file, but it's just not getting applied. I also tried the advice given in this question: [Applying templates to pages loaded from Wordpress Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851601/changing-a-template-on-a-blog-page-wordpress-3-5-1) and turned on the wp_debug. It didn't return any errors to me. I'm really lost on this. Bellow is the code from the template file. As you can see if you look at the source code of my blog, they do not match because this template file is not being applied. Anyone know what is causing the template to be applied?

Code from template file:

```
<?php
/*
  Template Name: Blog Template
 */

get_header();
?>

<span>Is this thing on?</span>
<div id="blog_content"> 

    <?php
    query_posts('post_type=post');
    if (have_posts()) {
        while (have_posts()) {
            the_post();
            ?>
            <div class="blog_post">
                <div class="post_wrap">
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <div class="entry_date"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></div>
                    <?php
                    the_content();
                    ?>
                    <div class ="post_foot">
                        <div class="comment_links">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">View Comments / Leave a Comment</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="social_shares">
                            Share this article with your frenz!
                            <ul class="share_links">
                                <li><a class="fb_share_link" target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php esc_url(the_permalink());?>"></a></li>
                                <li><a class="twitter_share_link" target="_blank" href="#"></a></li>
                                <li><a class="google_share_link" target="_blank" href="#"></a></li>
                                <li><a class="reddit_share_link" target="_blank" href="#"></a></li>
                                <li><a class="pin_share_link" target="_blank" href="#"></a></li>
                                <li><a class="linkedin_share_link" target="_blank" href="#"></a></li>
                                <li><a class="mail_share_link" target="_blank" href="#"></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    }
    ?>

    <div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('Older posts'); ?></div>
    <div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer posts'); ?></div>

</div>
<div id="blog_sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar_block">
        <div class="sidebar_wrap">
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_block">
        <div class="sidebar_wrap">
            Hello! This is a test to make sure adding another block here won't hurt anything but let's be honest it probably will break the internet.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Update: No matter what template file I change it too in the admin, it does not change!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay Just found a solution.

Turns out all I had to do was go in to the admin panel, then go to

> settings > reading

and change the posts page to "-Select-" and it then it started reading immediately from my template file. I figured out that stupid WordPress has some dumb Hierarchy system in place where if you tell it which page is the posts page it pulls a different template file. (which file? I don't know

Really dumb if you ask me, considering it just cost me about 5 hours to figure that one out and no one was engaging me on this question so I figured I'd leave it up in case anyone else had this same issue.